# Can i do this code python with snowball?

Tags: stemming, snowball

The word length is 5. I want to delete the letter in position 0 and the letter in position 3

with python seems like this :

`word = word[1:3] + word[4] #this is with python`

The question is, How i can do it with snowball ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the  solution seems like this:

```
do(
    [substring] among (
            $p1 ($word_len == 5 delete)
      )
      markto $p2
      [substring] among (

            'cha' (atmark==$p2 delete)
      )
  )
```